# Android project contains extra files beginning with "._"

Tags: android-studio

I have an Android project which is not coded by me and I opened it in my PC using Android Studio. For almost every file in the project, there is another file with the same name but beginning with "._". What are these files?

[image]

Should also note that these files do not prevent to build & run the app.

Edit: Project was coded on Mac and my OS is Windows

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the other answer, "._" files are used to store file metadata, similar to .DS_STORE files on Mac OS.

You can configure Android Studio to ignore these files by adding them to the "Ignored Files and Folders" list at Preferences -> Editor -> File Types -> Ignored Files and Folders.

[image: Android Studio Preferences Dialog - Ignored Files and Folders Settings]

Comment: doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

The `._` files is automatically created by Mac to store file information that would otherwise go into an extended attribute on HFS+ (Apple native) or Unix/UFS volumes.

You can safely remove them because they don't relevant to your project at all.

The details about that can be seen at SO sister-site https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them. I'll quote the accepted answer here:

> You can't avoid them (but see the dot_clean answer by Saeid Zebardast
>   --they can be removed from a directory if that is what you need). They're created to store file information that would otherwise go into
>   an extended attribute on HFS+ (Apple native) or Unix/UFS volumes; in
>   earlier Mac OS this would be the resource fork. Finder file operations
>   will create them automatically to store the icon information, plus
>   Time Machine stores some information in them so if you copy a file
>   backed up via TM it will have that information copied as well.
>
> (This is nothing new; I've noticed that XP and later leave various
>   turds around as well, although not quite as many.)